# Class constructor [ClassName] cannot be invoked without 'new' after upgrading to Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have a large application that is currently working fine in Angular 9.1.13.  After upgrading to either Angular 10 or 11, I get the run time error below in the console.

> Class constructor FormControl cannot be invoked without 'new'

This happens when a class that I created extends FormControl.  At first glance I thought it was only related to Angular but I see the same error with other classes that I created that extend other classes for example, BehaviorSubject from RxJs.

I read  a few articles before posting this question and the closest issue was posted in the Angular forums ([Angular Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18067)).  In that article they recommend changing the tsconfig.json "target" property to "es2015".  I changed the target from "es5" to "es2015" but the issue persists.  Below is the tsconfig that I'm using.  The exact same configuration works perfectly in Angular 9.  Any idea of what I'm missing?

TypeScript 4.1.4
Webpack: 4.43
ts-loader: 7.0.5

```
{
"compilerOptions": 
   {
      "target": "es2015",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ],
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noImplicitThis": false,
      "strictNullChecks": false,
      "allowUnreachableCode": false,
      "downlevelIteration": true
    },
  "angularCompilerOptions": 
      {
         "entryModule": "/src/app.module#MyModule",
         "skipMetadataEmit": true,
         "enableIvy": false
      },
      "exclude": [ "node_modules"]
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing the error? Can you just add `new` as the error suggests?

Comment: new is being used on the extended class but the error still persists.

Comment: you still didn't show the code!